# /etc/shadow and /etc/passwd privilege - why is it writable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, solaris

```
sghk1> id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root)

sghk1> ls -l /etc/shadow
-r--------   1 root     sys         4045 Aug 24 15:52 /etc/shadow

sghk1> ls -l /usr/bin/passwd
-r-sr-sr-x   1 root     sys        26764 Jan 11  2012 /usr/bin/passwd
```

When I try to vi edit and the file, and :wq, it prompt the below

```
"/etc/shadow" File is read only
```

Why is it that when I call /usr/bin/passwd, the file is writable/changeable by the executable , but when I try to manually edit as root, I can't

Comment: If you **really** want to write, use `:wq!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `root`, you can do "anything", but programs such as `vi` will make checks to advise you.  `vim` (which is what you probably are using) will allow you to write to a *read-only* file using `:w!` (an exclamation mark).

The `passwd` program is designed to update `/etc/shadow`, and will use whatever combination of `chmod`, `write`, etc., which is needed without bothering to advise the user.

As an ordinary user (not running as `root`), of course, `vi`(`m`) cannot update `/etc/shadow`.  The `/usr/bin/passwd` program works because it uses the setuid feature (the "s" when you do `ls -l /usr/bin/passwd`).

Comment: does that means that the usr/bin/passwd is also somehow ignoring the fact that the /etc/shadow is read only.. my logic is that if the passwd program is using setuid to execute with root permission, then naturally root should is able to write to the file. so the reason it can't is because vi is making some checks against the file. am i right ?

Comment: The `/usr/bin/passwd` program can change the permissions because it runs with `root` privilege.

Comment: does that mean the passwd program changes the permission of the shadow file both before and after making changes to the file ?

Comment: The source code is at http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-shadow/shadow.git/tree/ (it goes through several steps to ensure that only one process is updating the files at any point).

Answer (score 2):

The file that you have referenced (`/etc/shadow`) does not show the *writable flag* in its [permissions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes).  `vi` or `vim` by default won't write to a file that doesn't have the writable flag, even as root or as the owner of the file, unless you override its behavior with an exclamation point.

You can use `:w!` to write to the file, ignoring the fact that the writable flag is missing.

Answer (score 0):

See the permissions you have on the file, root is the owner and the root itself has only read permission. To change it you should do "chmod u+w /etc/shadow" as root and it will give "yourself" the write permission.